# Of vs no Of (Preposition)

Tags: prepositions

I read this quite recently.

> The village **of** Beddgelert has shown that it is possible to reverse soil degradation.

Versus

> The village Beddgelert has shown that it is possible to reverse soil degradation.

Which one sounds more appropriate?
Also, In Geography, I read,

> The state **of** Rajasthan is endowed with wind and solar energy.

What difference does it make to say

> Rajasthan is endowed with wind and solar energy.?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's syntactically valid to omit the preposition ***of*** in OP's examples, but idiomatically uncommon. A bit of background from [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/science/toponymy) on ***Toponymy*** (taxonomic study of place-names)...

> *Habitation and feature names are either **generic** or **specific**, or a combination of the two. A generic name refers to a class of names such as river, mountain, or town. A specific name serves to restrict or modify the meaning of the place-name.*

We only usually only use the "combined" naming convention if it's contextually important to specify the "generic" component - either because the "specific" element is likely to be unfamiliar to the audience, or to disambiguate *(State of New York, City of New York)*.

I would say the *default* is that if specified, the generic component is normally followed by ***of*** [SpecificName] with "population centre" place names *(village, town, city)*. But "geographical features" are often referred to using the specific component as an initial-position adjective *(Table Mountain, the River Thames)*. Note that *the river **of** [RiverName]* is extremely unlikely, but *the Forest **of** [ForestName]* and *[ForestName] Forest* are both in common use.

Unfortunately, the situation is complicated by things like ***Mount Everest***, where the optional generic ***mount = mountain*** has effectively been incorporated into a "double-barrelled proper noun" (and nobody ever refers to *the mountain [of] Everest* or *Everest mountain*), and ***County Kildare*** (rarely *the county [of] Kildare*). It's also worth noting the capitalisation of proper nouns such as *The **Forest of Dean** is in the county of Gloucestershire*.

---

In short, there are no clear-cut rules as to which format would be used for any given referent. But as a general principle, the preposition ***of*** should be included in any reference where the "specific" component is unfamiliar or ambiguous, *unless* you're already aware that for the *specific* case in point, a different convention has become firmly established.

Answer (score 1):

It is usual to insert the preposition **of** between the entity and its name. It makes for easier reading and sounds more natural. Without **of** there is a need for a momentary pause to make it clear that the entity and the place are one and the same.

> The village of Upperdee
>
> The town of Newfort
>
> The port of Dover
>
> The city of London
>
> The province of Ontario

The preposition may also be omitted in certain constructions, often after you have already introduced the place concerned, such as:

> Ahead of us we could see our destination. The city, York, whose cathedral...
>
> A cluster of pretty houses lay ahead. The village, Upperdee, which is situated on the river,

In these instances **of** is optional. But omitting it makes it clear that the destination and the city are one and the same, as are the houses and the village.

Regarding your question about Rajasthan, introducing it with **the state of** informs us of its status (not a town or city but a state). For those who know it well, it hardly matters. But for the world at large it might be useful information.